# Recommend a desktop and voice recording app

Tags: voice-recording, desktop-recording

Can anyone share a recommendation and their experiences with an app that I could use to create tutorials for internal use within my company.

The tutorials will be of a technical nature, like HOW TOs on certain topics, like conventions we follow when creating UIs, explanations of frameworks, APIs etc.

I would like the app to record my desktop and voice as I'm talking and store it in a reasonably standard format.  I'll then upload the files somewhere for people to view whenever.

Cheers.

Comment: This is more of a usability/program question rather than a programming question. I recommend you ask on superuser.com and you'll likely get a quicker answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Camtasia Studio](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.asp) is one such "de-facto" solution.

Comment: Thanks.  Sold when I saw it's from the same group as do SnagIt.